# Troubleshooting ui.item in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using the jQuery sortable plugin and one of the things I can do is on change I can run a function:

```
$( "#listA, #listB" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected_sortable",
    delay: 100,
    receive: function(event, ui) {
                alert(ui.item.text());
            }
}).disableSelection();
```

In this case I'm using an alert. How do I figure out what objects are in the ui.item?  `text()` currently gives me the text I've used in the but how do I find out all of the other information?  **More specifically the id?**  I couldn't find information on this in the [jQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable).  Is there a way to use Firebug to find out what functionality ui.item has?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log("%o", ui.item);
```

or set a breakpoint inside the function with firebug, then right click the ui and 'inspect in dom'.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
ui.item.attr("id");
```

`ui` is a normal jQuery wrapped element